# How to make app (with username/password login) know that a user is logged in?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I'm trying to make a login screen and made a database with Firebase by Google. The way I tried to make accounts in database is just by making a new child which is "Users" and then the next child would be a user (which is uniquely defined with a unique username). Then, user has other attributes and an attribute called loggedIn which is set to String 'false' but when on loginScreen login goes successfully set to String 'true'. How can I know after login and when that LoginViewController goes away which account has logged in exactly on that phone (simulator at the time) because there can be more users at one time with the attribute value 'loggedIn' set to 'true' and because of that can't go back to database to check that. I'm really new at this and don't know if this whole approach is okay by making in real-time database something like that and actually checking that by the attribute. Maybe I have to use some kind of a local database or something similar?

Swift 4, iOS development, Xcode 9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to persist locally the login status you may use UserDefaults. Just have a key called currentUser and set the value as his unique Id.
Once a user logs out just clear that key.
You can also use that to determine whether to launch the login screen when the app opens.

But it may be better to use something like AWS Cognito or similar services to handle user management.

Are you building an iOS app only or a cross-platform project?

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I'm building it just for iOS.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is the perfect answer for you. However, some of my apps use CloudKit and the login is authenticated and only then opens up areas of the app on the user's device. I'm sure if you wanted to check the status of successful logins, the authentication on the cloud could update as confirmation and you could subsequently access the cloud database using the CloudKit Dashboard.

It's quite intuitive and works seamlessly with Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

I have a class called LoginManager, defined as an NSObject. Included in there is an optional String variable called accessToken with setter and getter functions for saving and retrieving my access token, including an option for clearing the token which would be used upon logout. There is also a function to check the status of the key.

```
var accessToken: String? {
    get {
            return //key from storage
        }

    set {
        if newValue == nil {
            //remove key from storage
        } else {
            //save key to storage
        }
    }
}

func isUserLogedIn() -> Bool {
    return self.accessToken != nil
}
```

In my own case, I have an application manager object that changes the root view controller based on this info.

```
LoginManager.singleton.isUserLogedIn() ? loadMainView() : loadLoginView()
```

So the resulting view controller is never loaded unless the user is logged in. Is that useful to you?

Comment: To chime in on one of the other answers, the storage we use in the getter and setter is UserDefaults, but I thought I would leave that up to the OP, since they already built a database for the app.